# Vs code same search on all editor groups

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, having 2 or 3 files opened simultaneously inside editor (different groups) it is very difficult to search the same text over them as we must enter the search contents for each one of the groups.

Is there a setting or plugin that enables the same search text to be shared by all groups as happens for example in Visual Studio?

(That means pressing F3 on another group would search for the same text as the previous one)

Answer (score 0):

Until now the only solution I've found has to do with performing a "search in files" instead of a "local search" and specify for "files to include" only the currently editing files.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only way to "share" Ctrl+F3 searches to files that are in another group is to move them into the same group :(